# Delete current (non-atomic) s-expression in Emacs

Tags: emacs, paredit

Is there an easy way to delete the smallest-possible non-atomic s-expression based on the cursor location? I want to turn this (the "|" is the cursor)

```
(defun foo (bar)
  (if bar
      |789
    (+ 456 123)))
```

into this

```
(defun foo (bar)
  |)
```

It seems like a useful thing to be able to do, but I couldn't find a relevant (one-step) command on the [Paredit cheat sheet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PareditCheatsheet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find a predefined command either.

Fortunately, with Emacs it's really easy to implement your own.

For example:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c C-d") 
    (lambda () (interactive) (backward-up-list) (paredit-kill)))
```

Comment: I recommend to use `C-M-u C-M-k` instead of the atomic command.

Comment: @m2ym Thanks very much! Spent a bunch of time trying to find the function for this. For some reason, `paredit-backward-up` (bound to `C-M-u`) is not listed in the ParEdit reference card (at least, not the on the one that comes up first in Google)...

Answer (score 1):

`C-M-u` does the right thing inside strings in paredit 23, so `C-M-u C-M-k' will work even inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed cursor is not at a number 789, but inside a string "Foo" at this place.

Than this command will fail.

That's why ar-kill-parentized-atpt and related extensions exist at

http://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/